# $x^2+y^2=25$ vs $y=\sqrt{25-x^2}$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Why does every graphing calculator give me a graph with a circle when I give it $x^2+y^2=25$ (circle equation), but only half a circle when I give it $y=\sqrt{25-x^2}$ (same, only solved for $y$)?

Cheers.

Comment: That *isn't* solved for y.  That is solved for *positive values* of y.  All the negative values are thrown away.

Comment: Should be $|y|=\sqrt{25-x^2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you solve the equation $$x^2+y^2=25$$ for $y$ you must write $$y=\pm\sqrt{25-x^2}$$

Comment: Isn't it obvious that a square root of any positive number is plus/minus?

Comment: Noo! No way.$\sqrt{9} =3$ only.$\sqrt{9} \neq \pm 3 $

Comment: no the square root of non negative number is $|x|$

Comment: @JaideepKhare $\pm 3^2=9$

Comment: no $$(\pm3)^2=9$$

Comment: You mean $(\pm 3)^2=9$, That's true., but $\sqrt{9} = \pm 3$ is **NOT**

Comment: @JaideepKhare oh! yes

Comment: "Isn't it obvious that a square root of any positive number is plus/minus?"  No.  *a* square root, like any other number, can either be positive or negative or zero, but it can only be *one* of those.  It can't be both.  If $n $ is positive then $n $ has *two* *different* square roots, one that is positive and another that is negative.  It *doesn't* have one square root that is both positive and negative at the same time.  That doesn't make any sense. The positive square root is $\sqrt n $ and the negative is $-\sqrt n $.

Comment: $\pm 3$ is not a single number.  It either represents a set of two numbers, or an unknown value that may be one or another number but we don't know which one.  The symbol $\sqrt{9} $ is NOT "any one of the numbers where $n^2=9$".  Instead $\sqrt {9} $ is the unique one and only  *non-negative* number where $n^2=9$ AND $n\ge 0$.  In other words $\sqrt {9}=3$.  Not $\pm 3$.  $3$. And $\sqrt {9} $ is only *one* of the square root*s*.  There are two.  And $\sqrt {9} $ is one of them. Not either one or one or the other.  It is *one* specific *positive* one.

Answer (score 3):

Because $x^2+y^2=25$ allows negative values of $y$ too, while the equation $y=\sqrt{25-x^2}$ doesn't.(Since $\sqrt{a}$ is always positive, $\forall ~a>0$
)

Answer (score 1):

Common misunderstanding for beginners. The following should clear up the confusion.

1. It's ok to say in words that the square root of $9$ is $\pm3$.
2. But when using $\sqrt{9}$ notation, one has to be careful. That notation denotes the non-negative value of the square root, namely, writing $\sqrt9$ means $+3$. It's a convention.
3. Thus, to indicate there are two roots, one has to write $\pm3$ or $\pm\sqrt{9}$ because $\sqrt9$ simply means $3$.

In general, if the square root is a real number, the convention is that the notation $\sqrt{...}$ denotes a non-negative value:

$$ \sqrt{x^2} = |x|.$$

Again, this convention does not apply to complex numbers.

Comment: I disagree with your first statement.   The square roots of $9$ are $\pm 3$.

Comment: I agree with your correction on the grammar. But my point is to say that the square root of 9 can be either $+3$ or $-3$ as long as you say in words.  As soon as you write it out using the notation $\sqrt9$, this notation represents a single non-negative root only.